# Android studio giving AssertionError: null error in new project creation

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ubuntu-14.04, environment

Friends
I am new in to android app development and When I am trying to setup the environment I am getting the error i am just confuse why it is happening with me I am using **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** and `java -version
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.3) (7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)`
 and when have download the `android-studio-ide-135.1641136-linux.zip` from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other) and when i am running the studio it starts well and after when I try to create a new project i am facing like this ![null
java.lang.AssertionError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPnlu.png) any one can please help me in solveing the problem

Comment: That's an IDE bug. Looking at the source code, it looks like its trying to set up its list of pages to show in the New Project Wizard, and it's hitting some sort of condition it never expects to see. I would recommend filing a bug at b.android.com.

Comment: @ScottBarta Thanks for your help I also feel so as i search in net and have file that bug.

Comment: i also had the same problem but i restarted the studio and it worked as a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research over net and R&D i found that my `SDK Manager` was not properly configured and was unable to download the minimum `SDK` but it's a bug too of an `IDE` so my recommendation is that if u find this kind of problem try to import an entire per-compiled project then when ever the `IDE` will open will open with some value. Some times in case of Linux it is some permission issue so we have to check all the permission carefully

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but on Windows 7 OS.  Apparently Android Studio had no idea where the Android SDK folder was located.  You can set this location under File -> Project Structure -> "SDK Location" or use Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S then "SDK Location".  You just have to specify the ..\Android\sdk folder location.  You can also set your Java Development Kit (JDK) location as well if that is not set properly.

Answer (score 0):

Remove .idea files from project it will fix your issue.